# Limit of summation of fractional parts

Tags: number-theory, summation, fractional-part

I have been trying to calculate the following limit of a fractional part without much success, as I am not very competent at mathematics. Could anyone provide any help please?

$lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x+1}\sum_{k=0}^x \{k/c\}$

Comment: What if $c$ is an integer ? What if $c = p/q$ is rational ?

Answer (score 0):

If c is irrational (but not zero), k/c has uniform distribution in (0,1).
Thus the average goes to 0.5. The rational case can be more difficult.

Comment: The rational case is easy ($p$ is inversible modulo $q$ so $\sum_{k=1}^{mq} \{ kp/q\} =\sum_{k=1}^{mq} \{ k/q\}$). Then for $c$ irrational find a sequence $p_n/q_n$ of rationals such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} q_n |c-\frac{p_n}{q_n}|  = 0$ to obtain the result.